# Web Api controller returning 404 despite returning payload

Tags: webapi

I have created a WebApi controller, and it's returning the payload OK (i.e. I see the correct response in the browser), however the status of the request is a 404, which obviously causes problems with JS clients.

Why is the status 404 when clearly the route exists?

I have even tried setting the response status explicitly:

`return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "hello");`

But still get a 404?

I'm using Sitecore version 8.2 update 4.

Controller:

```
public class SearchApiController 
    : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Search()
    {
        var searchResults = GetSearchResults();

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, searchResults);
    }
}
```

Route mapping via pipeline:

```
public class InitializeRoutes
{
    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Config:

```
    <pipelines>
        <initialize>
            <processor type="Feature.Search.Infrastructure.Pipelines.InitializeRoutes, Feature.Search" resolve="true" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeGlobalFilters, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
        </initialize>
    </pipelines>
```

Comment: You need to terminate the request, to stop further processing on the request. That would be my guess anyway, otherwise you need to share a bit more on how you've set this up.

Comment: @MarkCassidy updated with extra details

Comment: @MarkCassidy when you say "Terminate the request" - how would that be done?

Comment: What is the URL you are using to access the API?

Comment: `https://local-sitename/api/searchapi/search`

Comment: try to call https://local-sitename/api/sitecore/searchapi/search without any InitializeRoutes

Comment: This doesn't work for me. But originally I was using this URL successfully following this blog: https://sitecorecommerce.wordpress.com/2017/02/05/webapi-2-native-support-in-sitecore-8-2/ but this is using MVC controllers, not WebAPI. Switching to web api seems to break it.

Comment: Given my controller is getting hit OK, I can't help but think Sitecore is doing something later in the pipeline to change the response status...

Comment: @DavidMasters Do you have any custom pipeline processor that handle your 404 page?  Sitecore does not change the status code itself, this has to be something custom in your solution

Comment: @AhmedOkour that's it. A team member has added a processor that is assuming 404 status when there is not Sitecore item in context. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that another member of the team had added a custom pipeline to handle 404's. It's code was checking the Sitecore.Context.Item and returning a 404 status if null, which obviously it would be when invoking the api url.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Web API attribute routing which in Sitecore 8.2 is supported with no conflicts with ​`Sitecore.Services.Client`.

You don't even need to configure Web API to use attribute routing configurations, all you need to add is to add the route prefixes to your you controllers/Action like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/searchapi")]
public class SearchApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("search")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Search()
    {
        var searchResults = GetSearchResults();

        return  Ok(searchResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: @DavidMasters This could be obvious, but worth checking if the dll that has your controller is deployed to your bin, I didn't have any problem with the code above

Comment: @DavidMasters Also, Do you have any other custom route mapping?

Comment: It's definitely there. Just to re-iterate: when I type the url into the browser, it works - I can see the data. But in the network tab I can see the status is a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code. The `HttpResponseMessage` is deprecated and is replaced by `IHttpActionResult`. While there are probably better and more Sitecore-esque ways to achieve what you are doing here, a straight up modification of your code would look like this:

```
public class SearchApiController 
    : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Search()
    {
        var searchResults = GetSearchResults();
        if(searchResults == null)
            return NotFound();
        return Ok(searchResults);
    }
}
```

Reference: [Web API Best Approach for returning HttpResponseMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016057/web-api-best-approach-for-returning-httpresponsemessage)

Recommended followup reading: [Implementing a WebApi service using ServicesApiController in Sitecore 8](https://laubplusco.net/implementing-webapi-service-using-servicesapicontroller-sitecore-8/)

Comment: I was using `IHttpActionResult` originally but thought I'd try with the response message just to see if setting the status explicitly would make a difference. Is that article still applicable to 8.2?

Comment: I would assume so. Further, the article actually describes a better approach for Sitecore APIs - I just didn't want to jump out with a "you're all wrong" approach ;-)   I believe what is happening for you is, your API call executes but Sitecore continues to process the request - which then ultimately 404s. And that lies in the fact, that the request is not recognized as a full "API request" rather a "page request".

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check http://{HostName}/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx and verify your pipeline processor position?

I would suggest to move it to the last position by applying Sitecore patch configuration or move it to zzz config folder.

We are having the same setup(Sitecore 8.2 update-4) except the case I mentioned above and everything works fine.

Answer (score -1):

you can used SitecoreController like this and

> then use api/{controller}/{action}/{id} or api/SearchApi/Search

```
public class SearchApiController 
    : SitecoreController 
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Search()
    {
        var searchResults = GetSearchResults();
        if(searchResults == null)
            return NotFound();
        return Ok(searchResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its work find for me.Please check & apply.